# DIV incorrect positions after float:right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### [image: Heading]

I want to have one of my blocks(BBB) in the right side of screen. It's ok, but the other div(CCC) is getting up.How can I force to CCC dont to getting the empty space of BBB.Here is my code:

> ```
>                         <div class="row text-left">
>                          <div class="col-xs-2">
>                                 <h5>AAA</h5>
>                                 <field name="AAA"/>
>                             </div>
>                         </div>
>                         <div class="row text-left" style="float: right;">
>                             <div class="col-xs-2 ">
>                                 <h5>BBB</h5>
>                                 <field name="BBB" />
>                             </div>
>                         </div>
>
>                          <div class="row text-left" >
>                             <div class="col-xs-2">
>                                 <h5>CCC</h5>
>                                 <field name="CCC"/>
>                             </div>
>                         </div>
> ```

Comment: Just don't use css "float" property. There are a lot of newer alternatives. You can use flexbox or grid instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use css "float" property. There are a lot of newer alternatives. You can use flexbox or grid instead.

Here you have the solution of this problem using flexbox:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="aaa">aaa</div>
   <div class="bbb">bbb</div>
   <div class="ccc">ccc</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.aaa, .ccc {
   align-self: flex-start;
}
.bbb {
   align-self: flex-end;
}
```

You can read about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), or about grid [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: your code is working, but the size of my textareas,which are in these blocks are now very  small.

Comment: You can set their sizes in CSS too. Just write something like:

textarea {
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```css
div.col-xs-2 {
  position: relative;
}
div.col-xs-2:first-of-type {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
div.col-xs-2:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
div.col-xs-2:last-of-type {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: blue;
}
```